# ¿Detectar si un elemento es visible dentro de un NestedScrollView en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Necesito detectar si un elemento dentro de un scroll se está mostrandose en pantalla.

En mi banco de pruebas tengo un texto lorem impsum y después un botón `myBtn1`

Para detectar cuando se hace scroll en un `NestedScrollView`  uso

```
Button myBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtn1);
NestedScrollView scroller = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScroll);
if (scroller != null) {

     scroller.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

//aquí detectar si myBtn aparece en pantalla
         }
     });
 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi idea es obtener el `top` del botón y comparar si el `scrollY` es superior  para saber que el botón se ha visionado, teniendo en cuenta la altura del elemento scroll, así también mirar si ha desaparecido por arriba el botón.

¿Me pregunto si hay alguna función en Java para determinar si un elemento es visible / dibujado en pantalla?

Comment: No termino de entender lo que necesitas. Que yo sepa, un `NestedScrollView` se utiliza para crear un scroll dentro de un `ScrollView`, pero no entiendo porque quieres mostrar un botón en ese  `NestedScrollView`. Tengo una idea de como podrias hacerlo, pero no se cierto si es lo que pides. ¿Puedes dejar una imagen sobre lo que quieres hacer? Gracias.

Comment: Gracias, aunque ya te has contestado tu. A mi también me pasa. Formulo una pregunta y a los 5 min. se me a ocurrido la respuesta. :)

Comment: Lo de detectar un elemento lo estoy implementando en mi AboutScreen donde aparece la zona de novedades, se muestre el floatingActionButton con el icono "mandar un bug"

Comment: "Una imagen vale más que mil palabras".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado!

Una forma rapida para detectar un elemento esta en pantalla es comprobando los `rect bounds` (top,right,bottom,left) de un elemento con los `rect bounds` de otro.

**Detectar si está en pantalla**

Si se necesita detectar si el botón se está mostrándose en pantalla o no:

```
if (myBtn1 != null) {

    if (myBtn1.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Botón en pantalla");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "No está en pantalla");
    }
}
```

**Detectar si está en pantalla en su Totalidad**

Si se necesita detectar si el botón se está mostrándose parcialmente o en su totalidad dentro de la pantalla

```
if (myBtn1 != null) {

    if (myBtn1.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
        if (!myBtn1.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)
                || scrollBounds.height() < myBtn1.getHeight()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Botón en pantalla - parcial");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Botón en pantalla - Total");
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "No está en pantalla");
    }
}
```

**Ejemplo:**

```
final Button myBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtn1);
final NestedScrollView scroller = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScroll);

if (scroller != null) {

    final Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
    scroller.getHitRect(scrollBounds);

    scroller.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

            if (myBtn1 != null) {

                if (myBtn1.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Botón en pantalla");
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "No está en pantalla");
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: deberías marcar esta respuesta como correcta, alguna vez pregunte lo mismo y se realiza con un listener onScrollChangeListener detectando el area visible de la vista. El mismo Romain Guy me respondió.  +1

Comment: De aquí un par de días, cuando me deje el sistema de votación